# Openstack - hardware requirements

Tags: hardware, openstack, requirements

I've been needing a new VM host for some time now, and from working with/on AWS at work, "The Cloud" seems to be a good idea.

I've done some math, and no matter how I count, it's going to be cheaper to do it myself, than colo or something else. Plus, I really like lots of blinking lights :D

A year or so, I heard about Openstack and have been looking cursory at it since then. Seems big and complex (and scary!), and some friends who have been trying to do it at work for a year and still not quite finished/succeeded, indicate that it is what it seems :)

However, I like tormenting myself, so I've decided I'm going to give it a try. It does provide all the functionality, and then some, that I need. Theoretically, I could go with Vagrant, but that's not quite half-way to what I want/need.

So, I've been looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#Components and from that came to the following conclusion:

## Required: (Nova, Glance, Horizon, Cinder)

This seems to be the "core" services. I need all of them.

- Nova
  Compute fabric controller
- Glance
  Image service (for templates)
- Horizon
  Dashboard
- Cinder
  Block storage devices (can work with ZoL w/ 3rd party driver)

## Less important: (Barbican, Trove, Designate)

I really don't need any of this, it's more of "could be nice to have at some point".

- Barbican
  REST API designed for the secure storage, provisioning and management of secrets
- Trove
  Database-as-a-service provisioning relational and non-relational database engine
- Designate
  DNS as a Service

## Possibly not needed: (Neutron, Keystone)

These ones I don't know if I need. I have DHCP, VLAN, VPN, DNS, LDAP, Kerberos services on the network that work just fine, and I'm not replacing them!

- Neutron (previously Quantum)
  Network management (DHCP, VLAN)
- Keystone
  Identity service (can work with existing LDAP servers)

## Not needed: (Swift, Ceilometer, Ironic, Zaqar, Searchlight, Sahara, Heat, Manilla)

Meh! I'm doing this for me, for my basement and for my own development and enjoyment, so don't need that. Would be nice to go with a fully object based storage, but that's not feasible for me at this time.

- Swift
  Object storage system
- Ceilometer
  Telemetry Service (billing)
- Ironic
  Bare metal provisoning instead of virtual machines
- Zaqar
  multi-tenant cloud messaging service for Web developers (~ SQS)
- Searchlight
  Advanced and consistent search capabilities across various OpenStack cloud services
- Sahara
  Easily and rapidly provision Hadoop (storing and managing vast amounts of data cheaply and efficient) clusters
- Heat
  Orchestration layer (store the requirements of a cloud application in a file that defines what resources are necessary for that application)
- Manila
  Shared File System Service (manage shares in a vendor agnostic framework)

If we don't count storage (I already have my own block storage, which I can use with Cinder and some 3rd party plugins/modules) and compute nodes (everything that's left over will become compute nodes), can I run all this on one machine? With a hot standby/failover?

Everything is going to be connected to the same power jack, same rack, same [outgoing] network cable so more redundancy that that is overkill. I don't even need that, but "why not" :)

The basic recommendation I've heard is four to six machines. And after a lot of pestering the ones who said that, it turns out that "two storage, two controller, two compute". Which, is what I was thinking as well: Running this on two machines should be enough. They're basically only going to run Glance, Horizon and Cinder. And possibly Neutron and Keystone.

Neither of them seems to be very resource-heavy.

Is there something I'm missing?

Oh, and nothing of this is going to face the 'Net! It's all just for me.

Comment: A lot of folks use Intel NUCs for small deployments.  One model even has an alternative to iLO / ipmi.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is theoretically possible to bring up OpenStack without Keystone, it is almost practically impossible and makes the system pretty inconvenient to use.

You can definitely run full OpenStack on a machine (or even in a VM). Checkout the devstack (http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/) -- you just run a shell script to bring up a full working OpenStack setup.

As long as you are not worried about availability and your workload is minimal, single-node deployment is a pretty good start to get your hands wet.